# How can I connect kaikas wallet in the react native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, wallet, wallet-connect

I want to connect kaikas wallet in the react native.
I used @walletconnect/react-native-dapp to connect Metamask and Trust Wallet.
But Kaikas wallet wasn't appeared in the modal of walletconnect.
please help me to connect kaikas in the react native.
Thanks

I used expo react native project and @walletconnect/react-native-dapp.
Connecting Metamask and TrustWallet is working well but kaikas is not.